# delete detail TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to delete a detail from my table. I'm not calling to api. It's all from redux store.

This is my reducer.js:

```
          case billsTypes.DELETE_DETAIL:{

           const id = action.payload.data._id
              return{
                   ...state,
                   details: state.bill.detail.filter(item => item._id !== id)
                     }
                 }
```

This is my action.js

```
            export const deleteDetail = id => dispatch =>{

              dispatch({type: billsTypes.DELETE_DETAIL, payload: id});
              };
```

And this is the render when I'm executing the action:

```
             render(){

              const{detailItem,index,fields,isSubtotal} = this.props;

              return(


                 <tr key={index}>

                   <td>
                     <Field 
                      id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                      name={`${detailItem}.quantity`}
                      type='number'
                      component= {UtilityQuantity}
                      placeholder= '...quantity'
                      // label = "Quantity" 
                        />
                         </td>


                          <td>
                          <Field 
                           id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                           name={`${detailItem}.product.code`}
                           type="number"
                           component= {UtilityCode}
                           placeholder='...Product's code'
                           //label = "Product's code" 
                             />
                            </td>
                             <td>
                               <Field 
                                id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                                name={`${detailItem}.product.name`}
                                type="text"
                                component= {UtilityName}
                                placeholder='...Product's name'
                                // label = "Product's name" 
                                    />
                               </td>

                                  <td>
                                  <Field 
                                   id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                                   name={`${detailItem}.product.price`}
                                   type="number"
                                   component= {UtilityPrice}
                                   placeholder= '...Price'
                                   // label = "Product's price" 
                                     />
                                   </td>

                                    <td>
                                     <Field 
                                      id={`${detailItem}._id`}
                                      name={`${detailItem}.subtotal`}
                                      component= {UtilitySubtotal}
                                      placeholder= '...subtotal'
                                      // label = "Subtotal" 
                                          >
                                       {isSubtotal}
                                      </Field> 
                                      </td>

                                      <td>
                             {/* <button className='btn btn-light mr-2'
                                 type="button"
                                 title="Remove Detail"
                                 onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>

                                  Delete
                              </button> */}

                                        <a
                                         className='mr-2'
                                         href='#more'
                                        onClick={() => {
                                                 if (
                                                   window.confirm(
                                                    'Are you sure to want to delete the item?'
                                                        )
                                                         )
                                                    this.props.deleteDetail(detailItem._id);
                                                           }}
                                                       >
                                                     DELETE ITEM
                                                        </a>

                                                     </td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                       );

                                                        }

                                                       }
```

WHEN I'm clicking on DELETE ITEM I've got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

In these code lines:

```
                             case billsTypes.DELETE_DETAIL:{

                                const id = action.payload.data._id
                                      return{
                                         ...state,
                                   details: state.bill.detail.filter(item => item._id !== id)
                                             }
                                               }
```

I'm not calling api rest because I'm working from redux store.

How can I fix this error?, I need to solve this but I don't know can do it.

Comment: Seems to me as though your `payload` *is* your id, not an object containing a key of `_id`, as `action.payload.data._id` denotes. Instead, `id` is simply `action.payload`.

Comment: How should it be?

Comment: Well, I would assume `const id = action.payload`

Comment: I've just tried but now I can't delete the row from the table in bill form.